# convert a gpx file to a feature class loses ident field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gps, arcgis-10.3, gpx

Using the ArcGIS 10.3 gpx to feature tool ([GPX To Features (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000050000000))  the "ident" field is lost in the translation.

DNR Garmin is an option but has limits to the number of points it can process and I'm running into memory issues.

Is there another tried and tested method to translate from .gpx to .shp  whilst keeping the ident field intact or can the ESRI tool do this and I am missing somthing?

I have hundreds I am trying to batch.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop but am open to Python solutions.

Comment: The free Open Source program called GPS Babel is an amazing tool for converting to and from many GPS formats (including shp). You might explore that one. See http://www.gpsbabel.org/

Comment: I will do some reading on the documentation. You need to select the input format and output format. I selected: input = GPX XML, output = CSV and the attributes weren't carried across. I'll try other options.